# Samsung galaxy Y does not factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, power-on

Lately my samsung galaxy Y has been switching off at random times, and does not switch on again. Well it switches on, and the samsung logo appears, but then it just switches off again. I have tried factory resetting, by pressing volume up, power, and home button. Whilst doing that, the menu for factory resetting appears, and whenever I want to select the reset now option, it switches off again. What can I do? Please help me!!! Thanks :)

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: is the battery fully charged, and have you tried described steps with the charger connected? You could also try removing the battery for a few minutes to "reset the circuits" by making them definitely powerless.